# "a bit" vs. "some"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, writing-style

Disclaimer: I'm a German native.

I'm working on some software with a coworker from US. He just sent a message saying "*if we decide to actually publish this as a real package, I'd like to clean it up some*".

My German-inspired way of expressing this would have been "*clean it up a bit*" and this phrase was a surprise.

But since he's American, I thought I'd rather go here for some sound advice on good English.

Is "*clean up some*" more colloquial or would it also be used in written texts etc.?

Comment: Using "some" instead of "a bit" in this context is rather informal, but in other contexts "a bit of cheese/some cheese" it can be similarly formal (although "some" is usually, but not necessarily, a greater quantity than "a bit")

Comment: Some can equal a bit (10%) or can mean more (90%). I wouldn't use a bit to mean 'maybe a lot'.

Comment: I think that's right. It seems to me (a very non-native German speaker) that it's much the same as the difference between _ein Bisschen_ and _etwas_, in the same context.  _Etwas_ can cover a lot of ground without being ironic.

Comment: "Clean it up some" is more colloquial in AmE than in BrE. In BrE we are masters of the understatement and 'a bit' can mean 'a lot'.

Comment: My spouse is German and I was raised, and live in, the US.  I give you license to continue using "a bit."  And note that "clean it up some" sounds a little weird to me -- I'd expect "do some clean-up [of the code]" if "some" is chosen.  But it's so common to find incomplete editing in emails.  So, for an email, it's fine -- at least I understood what your colleague was trying to say.

Comment: As a Brit exposed to a lot of US TV and film "clean it up some" sure does sound folksy / Southern to me.

Comment: You can't say 'clean it up some' in UK English. That's not idiomatic. You'd have to say 'a bit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Cambridge explains,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/some) in American English the word "some" can be used to mean "by a small amount or degree; a little." (It's essentially a synonym of "somewhat.")